# Not able to read json files: Spark Structured Streaming using java

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a python script which is getting stock data(as below) from NYSE every minute in a new file(single line). It contains data of 4 stocks - MSFT, ADBE, GOOGL and FB, as the below json format

```
[{"symbol": "MSFT", "timestamp": "2019-05-02 15:59:00", "priceData": {"open": "126.0800", "high": "126.1000", "low": "126.0500", "close": "126.0750", "volume": "57081"}}, {"symbol": "ADBE", "timestamp": "2019-05-02 15:59:00", "priceData": {"open": "279.2900", "high": "279.3400", "low": "279.2600", "close": "279.3050", "volume": "12711"}}, {"symbol": "GOOGL", "timestamp": "2019-05-02 15:59:00", "priceData": {"open": "1166.4100", "high": "1166.7400", "low": "1166.2900", "close": "1166.7400", "volume": "8803"}}, {"symbol": "FB", "timestamp": "2019-05-02 15:59:00", "priceData": {"open": "192.4200", "high": "192.5000", "low": "192.3600", "close": "192.4800", "volume": "33490"}}]
```

I'm trying to read this file stream into a Spark Streaming dataframe. But I'm not able to define the proper schema for it.  Looked into the internet and done the following so far

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;



public class Driver1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, StreamingQueryException {


        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark_Streaming").master("local[2]").getOrCreate();
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);


        StructType priceData = new StructType()
                .add("open", DataTypes.DoubleType)
                .add("high", DataTypes.DoubleType)
                .add("low", DataTypes.DoubleType)
                .add("close", DataTypes.DoubleType)
                .add("volume", DataTypes.LongType);

        StructType schema = new StructType()
                .add("symbol", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("timestamp", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("stock", priceData);


        Dataset<Row> rawData = session.readStream().format("json").schema(schema).json("/home/abhinavrawat/streamingData/data/*");
        rawData.printSchema();
        rawData.writeStream().format("console").start().awaitTermination();
        session.close();        

    }
```

}

The output I'm getting is this-

```
root
 |-- symbol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- stock: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- open: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- high: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- low: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- close: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- volume: long (nullable = true)

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+------+-------------------+-----+
|symbol|          timestamp|stock|
+------+-------------------+-----+
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00| null|
+------+-------------------+-----+
```

I have even tried first reading the json string as a text file and then applying the schema(like it is done with the Kafka-Streaming)...

```
  Dataset<Row> rawData = session.readStream().format("text").load("/home/abhinavrawat/streamingData/data/*");
    Dataset<Row> raw2 = rawData.select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json(rawData.col("value"),schema)); 
raw2.writeStream().format("console").start().awaitTermination();
```

Getting below output, in this case, the `rawData` dataframe as the json data in string fromat,

```
+--------------------+
|jsontostructs(value)|
+--------------------+
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
```

Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out, Keep the following two things in mind-

1. While defining the schema make sure you **name and order** the fields exactly the same as in your json file.
2. Initially, use only `StringType` for all your fields, you can apply a transformation to change it back to some specific data type.

This is what worked for me-

```
    StructType priceData = new StructType()
            .add("open", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("high", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("low", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("close", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("volume", DataTypes.StringType);

    StructType schema = new StructType()
            .add("symbol", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("timestamp", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("priceData", priceData);


    Dataset<Row> rawData = session.readStream().format("json").schema(schema).json("/home/abhinavrawat/streamingData/data/*");
    rawData.writeStream().format("console").start().awaitTermination();
    session.close();
```

See the output-

```
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
|symbol|          timestamp|           priceData|
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[126.0800, 126.10...|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[279.2900, 279.34...|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[1166.4100, 1166....|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[192.4200, 192.50...|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[126.0800, 126.10...|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[279.2900, 279.34...|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[1166.4100, 1166....|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[192.4200, 192.50...|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[126.0800, 126.10...|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[279.2900, 279.34...|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[1166.4100, 1166....|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[192.4200, 192.50...|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[126.0800, 126.10...|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[279.2900, 279.34...|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[1166.4100, 1166....|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[192.4200, 192.50...|
|  MSFT|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[126.0800, 126.10...|
|  ADBE|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[279.2900, 279.34...|
| GOOGL|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[1166.4100, 1166....|
|    FB|2019-05-02 15:59:00|[192.4200, 192.50...|
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

You can now flatten the priceData column using `priceData.open`, `priceData.close` etc.

Comment: how to do it in python?